# Asp.net core MVC fetch image from DB based on the Category

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am sorry to bother with simple matters but i really cannot find a way out of this problem.

I am building a Gallery, which container different fields, one of those is Category.

Category Class is a public Enum, and i would like to retrieve all the images in the Database and display them in View based on my Category selection.

Here you can find the code that i wrote so far.

View:

```
<form method="get" asp-controller="Gallery" asp-action="index">
    <div style="height:60px;" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="row" style="padding-top:10px;">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        @Html.Editor("Name", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Name..." } })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">

                <select class="custom-select form-control mr-sm-2" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Category>()"></select>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <div class="row" style="padding-top:10px; padding-right:20px;">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control" value="submit">
                        <i class="fas fa-search fa-1x"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index(string Name, Category category)
{
    var model = _galleryRepository.GetAllImages();
    StringBuilder param = new StringBuilder();
    param.Append("&Name=");
    if (Name != null)
    {
        param.Append(Name);

    }
    if(Name != null)
    {
        model = _galleryRepository.SearchName(Name);
    }


    if(category != Category.All)
    {
        model = _galleryRepository.SearchCategory(category);
    }

    return View(model);


}
```

Model Category:

```
public enum Category
{
    All,
    Photography,
    Portrait,
    Nature
}
```

Model Gallery:

```
public class Gallery 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Like { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(40, ErrorMessage ="Name cannot exceed 40 characters")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Description cannot exceed 100 characters")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public string PhotoPath { get; set; }

}
```

I did Managed to create a search form based on the Name of the image and it works just fine. But when it come to retrieve the images based on the Category Selection, it does not work.
i used a breakpoint on the Controller on the If statment related to category, and i realized that the condition fires but the model inside no.

So i am asking to the expert for an explanation about how to fix it as it the first time that i work with Enum and retrieving datas based on Enum classes.

Thank you so much for your help and i hope i made clear my problem.

Comment: I would start by making your `<select>` have an `asp-for="Category"` attribute. This will give it the correct `name` attribute for model-binding to work when you post your values (it will also preserve the users selected value after post back). You will probably have to update your controller action parameter also from `category` to `Category`

Answer (score 0):

Change your view like below,then you could pass the selected item to category:

```
@model Gallery
<form method="get" asp-controller="Gallery" asp-action="index">
     //...
     <div class="col-md-5">
         <select asp-for="Category" class="custom-select form-control mr-sm-2" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Category>()"></select>
     </div>
     //...       
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default model binder won't work with Enum types. Either you need to change the parameter to of type string and convert it to it's equivalent enum type before performing the comparisions OR provide your own implementation of model binder and override the default one. If I were you, I will go with the simplest solution like below,

```
public IActionResult Index(string Name, string selectedCategory)
{
    var category = Enum.Parse(typeof(Category),selectedCategory,true);

    var model = _galleryRepository.GetAllImages();
    StringBuilder param = new StringBuilder();
    param.Append("&Name=");
    if (Name != null)
    {
        param.Append(Name);

    }
    if(Name != null)
    {
        model = _galleryRepository.SearchName(Name);
    }


    if(category != Category.All)
    {
        model = _galleryRepository.SearchCategory(category);
    }

    return View(model);


}
```